# Explanation of $A[adj(A)]$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> Suppose **A** is a singular square matrix.
>
> It is known that the $(i,j)$-entry of $A[adj(A)] = a_{i1}A_{j1} +
>  a_{i2}A_{j2} + \cdots + a_{in}A_{jn}$ $$  \begin{cases} det(A)  &
>  \text{if $i = j$} \\[2ex] 0, & \text{if $i ≠ j$} \end{cases} $$
>
> So $A[adj(A)] = det(A)I$
>
> Since $A$ is singular, $det(A) = 0$
>
> and hence $A[adj(A)] = 0I = 0$

While i understand that if $A$ is singular, $det(A) = 0$. 
I do not understand how does the above chain of $A[adj(A)] = a_{i1}A_{j1} +
 a_{i2}A_{j2} + \cdots + a_{in}A_{jn}$ leads to the conclusion that $A[adj(A)] = det(A)I$.

Please explain. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $(i,j)$ entry of the identity matrix $I$ is $1$ if $i=j$ and $0$ if $i \neq j$.  It follows that the $(i,j)$-entry of $\det(A) I$ is
$$
\begin{cases}
\det(A) & i = j\\
0 & i \neq j
\end{cases}
$$
Because they have the same $(i,j)$ entries, we can conclude that $A\operatorname{adj}(A)$ and $\det(A)I$ are the same matrix.

Comment: Thanks. However, how does it has any relation with $a_{i1}A_{j1} + a_{i2}A_{j2} + \cdots + a_{in}A_{jn}$?

Comment: $a_{i1}A_{j1} + a_{i2}A_{j2} + \cdots + a_{in}A_{jn}$ is just the expansion of the sum which gives you the $i,j$ entry, using the definition of matrix multiplication.  Note that when $i=j$, $a_{i1}A_{j1} + a_{i2}A_{j2} + \cdots + a_{in}A_{jn}$ is just a Laplace expansion of the determinant.